# Dropping timedeltas from dataframe based on length of time

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I would like to drop rows from my dataframe if the timedelta is greater than 16 hours...so far I have had no luck.

Dataframe:

```
    European Central Bank          0 days 20:35:45
    U.S. Federal Reserve           3 days 15:11:52
    U.S. Federal Reserve   84 days 22:19:14.465000
    Central Bank of (..)           0 days 16:20:58
    Bank of Israel                 0 days 11:30:42
```

My attempts:

```
dropped = dropped.drop(dropped[(dropped.diff.dt.hours > 16)].index)

dropped = dropped.drop(dropped[(dropped.diff.hours > 16)].index)
```

Error received:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'hours'
```

Update:
-new attempt:

```
dropped = dropped.drop(dropped[dropped.dt.total_seconds() /(3600)<16])
```

New error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df[1]=df[1].map(pd.Timedelta)
df[df[1].dt.total_seconds() /(3600)<16]
```

Output:

```
             0        1
4  Bank of Israel 11:30:42
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get the following error (I've updated the question to show how I ran it): AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dt'

Comment: df[1]=df[1].map(pd.Timedelta)  Convert it to a pd.TimeDelta type first.

Comment: It worked, thank you SO much! I actually ran it just with this:                              dropped = dropped[dropped['diff'].dt.total_seconds() /(3600)<16]